# Produce a secure block cipher round function (1 bit round key; 7 bit message)

Tags: math, cryptography, linear-algebra, encryption

We need to produce a block cipher round function with a 1 bit round key size and a 7 bit message size with the highest level of cryptographic security according to our measure of security.

## Introduction

We are going to need new symmetric encryption functions. We are at the point where we cannot improve the performance of integrated circuits very much simply by shrinking transistors. Furthermore, we are approaching the limits of the energy efficiency of transistors using conventional irreversible computation. The only way to surpass these limits is to use reversible computation. But to get the most out of reversible computation, one needs to use algorithms that are designed for reversible computation. Since the AES encryption protocol was not designed for reversible computation, it is probably a good time for cryptographers to produce, evaluate, and standardize new symmetric encryption functions that are efficient on fully reversible hardware/software. And as a bonus, cryptographic functions are more resistant to side channel attacks when we run them on reversible hardware since irreversible computation not only leaks energy, but irreversible computation leaks some information that can be used to decipher what is being encrypted.

In addition to the need for new cryptographic functions, the rise of AI will bring rise to new cryptoanalytic techniques that can be used to better evaluate the security of block ciphers (this is my personal opinion based on my personal research). Cryptographers can also employ new techniques for evaluating block ciphers including the application of invariants that measure the level of cryptographic security of block ciphers and always give isomorphic block cipher round functions the same level of cryptographic security (this makes it impossible to artificially inflate the security value by relabeling all the possible messages and round keys). Spectral techniques are one way of assigning each block cipher or block cipher round function a specific number that measures its cryptographic security. In this challenge, we shall apply one of these spectral techniques to measure the cryptographic security of some very simple block cipher round functions.

The goal of this challenge is to produce a very simple block cipher round function that minimizes a measure of its cryptographic insecurity. Since this kind of block cipher round function has a microscopic 7 bit message size, it is subject to brute force attacks, and it will probably not have any practical use whatsoever, but we can still measure the level of its cryptographic security in various ways.

The participants in this challenge do not need to have prior experience with evaluating block ciphers and such prior experience may not help very much.

## Spectral radius

If \$X\$ is a matrix, then the spectral radius is the value
\$\rho(X)=\max\{|\lambda|:\lambda\,\text{is an eigenvalue of}\,X\}.\$ It is well known that \$\rho(X)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|X^n\|^{1/n}\$ and this limit does not depend on the matrix norm chosen.

The spectral radius of a complex matrix \$X\$ can often be easily computed. If \$v_0\$ is an arbitrary vector and \$v_{n+1}=\frac{Xv_n}{\|Xv_n\|}\$ for all \$n\$, then \$\|Xv_n\|\$ will converge to the spectral radius \$\rho(X)\$ except in the case when \$X\$ has multiple eigenvalues with maximum absolute value.

## Challenge

Our goal is to produce a pair of permutations \$(P,Q)\$ of \$\{1,2,...,127,128\}\$ with the smallest associated spectral radius \$\rho((P_2+Q_2)/2)\$. The pair of permutations \$(P,Q)\$ should be thought of as the round function for a \$7\$ bit message and 1 bit round key size. If the round key is \$0\$, we perform the transformation \$x\mapsto P(x)\$ to the message \$x\$, and if the round key is \$1\$, then we perform the transformation \$x\mapsto Q(x)\$ to the message \$x\$. A lower spectral radius signifies a greater level of cryptographic security.

Let \$X=\{1,2,...,128\}\$. Let \$Y\$ be the collection of all unordered pairs of distinct elements in the set \$X\$. For example, \$Y\$ contains the pairs \$\{2,3\},\{56,57\},\{2,16\}\$ along with other pairs. The set \$Y\$ contains \$128\cdot 127/2=8128\$ elements.

If \$P\$ is a permutation of \$\{1,...,128\}\$, then the mapping \$P\$ induces a permutation \$P_0\$ of \$Y\$ defined by letting \$P_0(\{a,b\})=\{P(a),P(b)\}\$. Let \$U\$ be the real vector space generated by the basis \$Y\$. Let \$L\$ be the linear functional mapping \$U\$ to the field of real numbers defined by setting \$L(\{x,y\})=1\$ whenever \$x,y\$ are distinct. Let \$V=\ker(U)\$. Then \$V\$ is the subspace of \$U\$ generated by pairs \$\{u,v\}-\{x,y\}\$. We extend the mapping \$P_0\$ to a linear operator \$P_1:U\rightarrow U\$ by linearity. In other words,
\$P_1(\alpha_1\{x_1,y_1\}+\dots+\alpha_n\{x_n,y_n\})=
\alpha_1P_0(\{x_1,y_1\})+\dots+\alpha_nP_0(\{x_n,y_n\})\$
\$=\alpha_1\{P(x_1),P(y_1)\}+\dots+\alpha_n\{P(x_n),P(y_n)\}.\$ Let \$ P_2:V\rightarrow V\$ be the restriction of the operator \$P_1\$. The operator \$P_2\$ is the unique linear operator from \$V\$ to \$V\$ where
\$ P_2(\{u,v\}-\{x,y\})=P_1(\{u,v\})-P_1(\{x,y\})\$ whenever \$\{u,v\},\{x,y\}\in Y\$
Our goal is to minimize the spectral radius \$\rho((P_2+Q_2)/2)\$ of the average \$(P_2+Q_2)/2\$.

Given a pair of permutations \$P,Q\$ of \$\{1,2,...,127,128\}\$, set
we produce a Markov chain on the set \$\{\{x,y\}:x,y\in\{1,\dots,127,128\},x\neq y\}\$ where we transition from \$\{x,y\}\$ to \$\{P(x),P(y)\}\$ with probability \$1/2\$ and from \$\{x,y\}\$ to \$\{Q(x),Q(y)\}\$ with probability \$1/2\$.  This Markov chain is associated with a double stochastic matrix \$A\$. The doubly stochastic matrix \$A\$ has spectral radius \$1\$, but the second largest absolute value of an eigenvalue of \$A\$ measures how quickly powers \$A^n\$ of \$A\$ converge to the matrix where each entry is equal to each other. In other words, the second largest absolute value of an eigenvalue of \$A\$ measures how quickly iterating steps in the Markov chain approaches the uniform Markov chain. The second largest absolute value of an eigenvalue of \$A\$ is just the spectral radius \$\rho((P_2+Q_2)/2)\$.

The averaging operator \$(P_2+Q_2)/2\$ satisfies a weak version of the circular law; the eigenvalues of \$(P_2+Q_2)/2\$ should be non-uniformly distributed on the disk centered at zero with radius \$\sqrt(2)/2\$. Furthermore, if the permutations \$P,Q\$ are good enough, then the spectral radius of \$(P+Q)/2\$ should be approximately \$\sqrt(2)/2\$.

## Computing the spectral radius

One can easily use power iteration to compute the spectral radius of a sparse matrix except for one tiny but manageable problem. The matrix \$(P_2+Q_2)/2\$ will be a real matrix, and the eigenvalues of real matrices will be symmetric around the real number line. This means that imaginary eigenvalues of real matrices must always come in pairs. Now, since the real number line has zero area and since the eigenvalues of \$(P_2+Q_2)/2\$ satisfy the a sort of circular law (but for \$(P_2+Q_2)/2\$ the eigenvalues somewhat cluster near the boundary of the disk due to the unitarity of \$P_2,Q_2\$), the matrix \$(P_2+Q_2)/2\$ is more likely to have a pair of conjugate dominant eigenvalues rather than a single real dominant eigenvalue. One can instead use the Arnoldi iteration (which is a more advanced version of the power iteration) in order to find the dominant eigenvalue and spectral radius of \$(P_2+Q_2)/2\$.

## Format

In your answer, please specify the permutations P,Q that you use along with the spectral radius of \$(P_2+Q_2)/2\$ (which should be around \$\sqrt{2}/2\$).

There are two ways that you can specify your permutations.

1. You may write your permutations as tables. For example, `[4,5,6,1,2,3,7,8]` will denote the permutation of {1,...,7,8} where 1->4,2->5,3->6,4->1,5->2,6->3,7->7,8->8.
2. You may also write your permutations as products of disjoint cycles. For example, `(2,6)(3,7)(1,4,8,5)` will denote the permutation of {1,...,7,8} where 2->6,6->2,3->7,7->3,1->4,4->8,8->5,5->1.

## Sample answer (with reduced key size).

Here is a sample answer where (for simplicity) the permutation \$P\$ takes \$5\$ bits as input and out rather than \$7\$ bits (\$P\$ is a permutation of \$\{1,\dots,31,32\}\$).

P:
`(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26)(27,28,29)(30,31)`

Q:
`(1,31,29,23,27,12,16,8,6,10,17,2,9,5,24,11,14,7,30,4,19,32,26,15,3,20)(13,18,21,22,28)`

P:
`[ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 1, 28, 29, 27, 31, 30,32]`

Q:
`[ 31, 9, 20, 19, 24, 10, 30, 6, 5, 17, 14, 16, 18, 7, 3, 8, 2, 21, 32, 1, 22, 28, 27, 11, 25, 15, 12, 13, 23, 4, 29,
26 ]`

Loss: \$\rho((P_2+Q_2)/2)\$=0.705873796001...

Observe that the loss is less than \$\sqrt{2}/2\$ but not by much. For this example, I made a moderate effort to minimize the value \$\rho((P_2+Q_2)/2)\$

We observe that the permutations \$P,Q\$ are uninterpretable, so for these permutations, no information about the algorithm used to produce \$P,Q\$ can be gained from the permutations \$P,Q\$ themselves. Here, the answerers are encouraged to post the code/pseudocode used for generating the permutations \$P,Q\$ or a description of the algorithm or technique used to produce \$P,Q\$.